# how to find minimum element's index in specific matrix's columns

Tags: matlab

I have matrix `C (m x n)`

I need to find the indices of the minimum element within specific columns (`m+1` to `n-1`).

```
d = min(c(c>0));
[x,en] = find(c == d);
```

please help

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you looking for the minimum element in each column of the subset? Or the minimum element in the subset?

Comment: Give a small numerical example with desired output. As it stands, it's difficult to know what you want

Comment: am looking for the minimum element in the subset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use min() for that:

`g = c(:,m+1:n-1);     %get the subset first
[d,ind] = min(g(g>0)); %get the minimum and index of that minimum`

Comment: already the columns is from 1 to n , but I need to search for minimum from m+1 to n-1

Comment: Why dont you first get your subset (`g = c(:,m+1:n-1);`) and then find the minimum and index (`[d,ind] = min(g(g>0))`);

Comment: thanks scott , it is good idea but I need befor to define zeros matrix as the same size of this nice group g=(m,m+1:n-1);;;;please help

Comment: THAX ALOT SCOTT;; IT WORKS WELL

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want,

```
Cm = C(:,m + 1 : n - 1);
d = min(Cm(Cm>0));
[row,col] = find(Cm == d);
if numel(col) > 0
   col = col + m;
end
```

Comment: col update command is not correct ,bcoz if n from 1 to 9 and m from 1 to 4 , and It find col=8 it will be 12;;;I need just search from 5 to 9

Comment: @osman `m=4` and `n=9` and it will search `5:8` you said `m+1:n-1`

Comment: really; I try it but it gives more than the real dimension ;;thanx MAN